# Seg-fault when trying to access flathub via Ubuntu on Windows-10

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, flatpak

I'm running into a segmentation fault when trying to get started using flatpak and flathub on Ubuntu on Windows 10. My Windows 10 setup is actually a VM running on a Windows 8.1 laptop, but I don't think that's the issue.
I was able to get flatpak installed, but when trying to access flathub it just immediately seg faults. On the flatpak.org website, they say that you can add the Flathub repository with this command:

$ flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrep

But that as admin results in the following error:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Can anybody with experience using flathub on Ubuntu 16.04.3 on Windows 10 explain how they got that to work? Thanks.